# Refresh plural route model when new record is saved

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a route that looks like so:

```
model() {
  return this.store.query('my-model', {
    offset: this.get('offset'),
    limit: this.get('limit')
  })
}
```

I use this in a route like `/my-models`, and render a list of the models.

Then, in a route like `/my-models/new`, I make and save a new model. However, when I save the new model, the list of models doesn't get updated to reflect the new presence of the new model.

I think this is because `store.query` doesn't monitor the store, it only fetches from the server. However, when I try `store.findAll`, which I believe should monitor the store for changes, it returns *every* record, not just the ones between the offset/limit params.

Is there any way to keep the pagination working, while adding having newly created records automatically add to the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use push method after you saved new model. Smth like this:

```
var store = this.get('store');
var newModel = store.createRecord('my-model');
newModel.set('param', 'param value')
  .save()
  .then(function () { store.push('my-model', newModel); })
```

Docs: http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_push

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about this one, but if you are using Ember Data 1.13 you could try with the new reload settings.

The documentation for `findAll` (which I know is not what you want) says:

```
store.findAll('user');  //goes to the server the first time
store.findAll('user');  //after that returns from cache, but updates in background
store.findAll('user', { reload: true });  //enforces getting fresh data
store.findAll('user', { backgroundReload: false });  //opts out of background updating
```

If you try `backgroundReload: true` with `query` (as third argument) would that refresh the query in the background?

Comment: Doesn't appear to change anything :(